# Deployed Django instance not recognising a file as a file

Tags: python, django, csv, iis

I have a deployed django webapp which has been working fine. It scrapes sites for newly published .csv files and then uses them for data analysis which is then returned to the user.

The most recent .csv is not being recognised as a file on the deployed version, but is on the test version on my local machine. The structure is as follows:

```
-indicator-analyser
  -Analyser
    -AnalysisScripts
    -uploads
       -data
         -2017
           -Monthly_File_Jun_Final.csv
           -Monthly_File_Sep_Final.csv
```

When a user attempts to run the script on the `Monthly_File_Jun_Final.csv`, the webapp performs as expected. When they run the same script on `Monthly_File_Sep_Final.csv`, django throws an error as there is no file found. I have taken the file path that is passed in and used that to open the file in explorer, and I have used the same file path to load the .csv as a dataframe in pandas within the console with no problems.

The path that is passed to the loading script is:

```
C:\\webapp\\indicator-analyser\\Analyser/uploads/data/2017/Monthly_File_Sep_Final.csv
```

When this is evaluated using `os.path.isfile(filepath)`, it is being returned as `False`. However, when the other file is selected, this is returned and recognised as a file:

```
C:\\webapp\\indicator-analyser\\Analyser/uploads/data/2017/Monthly_File_Jun_Final.csv
```

Just for reference, this is running on a IIS server. I have restarted the machine and the server to no avail.

To conclude, I can access this file:

- through the console
- on my local instance
- through my file explorer

But it is not recognised as a file in the live django instance.

Comment: Can you still show the code where you try to access the file?

Comment: It is a little convaleuted - the data set has its own class, and the filename has a function to add the time frame to it and then the filename is placed within a path depending on the time frame and data set. I know where it is failing, I have output the file paths as the point of failure (above). Both file path examples are the same class with the same function adding the tiemframe. The `Jun` file passes `if os.path.isfile(filepath)` as `True` whereas the `Sep` one is `False`.

Comment: Try opening a Python shell in the folder and doing `os.listdir` Triple check the characters and spelling.

Comment: @sytech Yes, I did do this and the file appears. I outputted the filepath from django, and then tried `os.path.isfile(filepath)` in the console and this was evaluated as `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by deleting the scraped file and redownloading it, placing it in the exact same place. I do not know why this has fixed it, but it is now working.